# Conventional Commit tools for non-JS projects

Tags: github, conventional-commits

Is there a way to enforce conventional commits in a non-node/non-npm/non-js project?? (Other than pre-commit hooks as they can be easily overridden)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I found nothing... Too much of them are not ready enough or simply deprecated...